# A question about nonlinear ODE and chaos

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chaos-theory

I'm just being curious, but is it true or false, that every 3 dimensional nonlinear ordinary differential equations, after rightful parameterizing, can become chaotic? If not, what kind of 3-D ODE can become chaotic after choosing the right parameter? Please give some reference if possible.

Comment: There is no accepted definition of chaos, so answers may vary. Also, what do you mean by "after rightful parametrizing"?

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong multiply or add any term with a number.

Comment: I don't think anybody can prove something on _every 3 dimensional nonlinear ordynary differential equation_. That being said, you can read about the [Lorenz system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system)

Comment: Surely the nonlinear ODE with separated variables are not chaotic, I think the Lorenz maps of the phase portrait of the chaotic ODE are concave functions, like a logistic map